# processBuilder not finding the main class

Tags: java, processbuilder

The command that is built is working fine on the command prompt but it not working in eclipse . This is how this looks :

```
            String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
        cmds.add(javaHome+"/bin/java");
        cmds.add("-cp");
        cmds.add(_devInstallConfig.getProperty("CP"));
       // CP = ("D:\Perforce\depot\nginst\src13920\nginst-install\repo-bootstrap-classpath-13.9.2.0-170213.1854.jar");
        cmds.add("com.oracle.cie.repository.stager.CarbStager");
        cmds.add("-repoURL "+repoURL);
        cmds.add("-props");
         cmds.add(_devInstallConfig.getProperty("PROPERTIES_FILE_LOCATION"));
         //PROPERTIES_FILE_LOCATION=("C:\Users\bpurana.ORADEV\Desktop\carb.properties");
        cmds.add("-repoBaseDir");
        cmds.add(_ngInstallLocation.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());
        //repoBaseDir=("D:\Perforce\depot\nginst\src13920\nginst-install");
        cmds.add("-PUBLISH_TYPE=BOTH");
        cmds.add("-CARB_OUTPUT_DIR="+temp_file);
        cmds.add("-NGINST_VERSION");
        cmds.add(_devInstallConfig.getProperty("NGINST_VERSION"));

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
        pb.directory(_ngInstallLocation.getParentFile());
        Process process = pb.start();
```

The error that I am seeing is this : 
Error: Could not find or load main class com.oracle.cie.repository.stager.CarbStager

Edit : I have updated the code snippet with the actual code ( and sharing sample examples of what each value means)

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? What is in the stdout/stderr of `process`?

Comment: I doubt this is your actual code, unless `\P`, `\d`, `\n` etc all *happen* to be valid Java string escape sequences. All of your path separators need to be escaped in string literals, e.g. `D:\\Perforce\\depot\\...`.

Comment: "...all happen to be valid Java string escape sequences" but even then, they almost certainly don't mean what you intend.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean ? So this is what I see being passed to the process builder :

Comment: Have you made sure that the jar given in the CP actually contains that class?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121/bin/java, -cp, D:\Perforce\depot\nginst\src13920\nginst-install\repo-bootstrap-classpath-13.9.2.0-170213.1854.jar, com.oracle.cie.repository.stager.CarbStager, -repoURL http://artifactory-slc.oraclecorp.com/artifactory/fmw-virtual, -props, C:\Users\bpurana.ORADEV\Desktop\GDR_bracnhing_tool\carbStager.properties, -repoBaseDir, D:\Perforce\depot\nginst\src13920\nginst-install, -PUBLISH_TYPE=BOTH, -CARB_OUTPUT_DIR=D:\Perforce\depot\nginst_1487754099253,  -NGINST_VERSION, 13.9.2.0-170131.2202

Comment: @bhavs I mean that a string literal `"yes\no"` does not print as `yes\no`. It means `yes<newline>o`. So, your edit to the code makes more sense.

Comment: The jar in the classpath contains a mainfest entries which point to the class in question here, by itself it does not contain the class

Comment: @RealSkeptic first line of the question.